# converting a list of dictionary from a single column of a Data Frame into different columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary, data-wrangling

**I have a Data Frame named "data"**

```
  updated_at          values                            user_id
0 2020-08-18    [{'value': 3742, 'key': '0'},       178414113
                 {'value': 3813, 'key': '1'}, 
                 {'value': 3918, 'key': '2'}, 
                 {'value': 2956, 'key': '3'}]   
1 2020-08-19    [{'value': 3542, 'key': '0'},       152285823
                 {'value': 2563, 'key': '1'}, 
                 {'value': 3218, 'key': '2'}, 
                 {'value': 2152, 'key': '3'}]
```

**i want to convert it like this.**

**updated_at    value          key            user_id**

```
0 2020-08-18      3742           0               178414113
1 2020-08-18      3813           1               178414113 
2 2020-08-18      3918           2               178414113
3 2020-08-18      2956           3               178414113
4 2020-08-19      3542           0               152285823
5 2020-08-19      2563           1               152285823
6 2020-08-19      3218           2               152285823
7 2020-08-19      2152           3               152285823
```

please help me .
i tried

```
data_new = pd. Data Frame ( data ['values'].values. to list(), index= data. index)
```

but it did not worked.

Comment: Have you looked into the `explode()` method?

Comment: explode is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `explode()` method to expand your column of lists into a separate row for each entry in those lists. Then you can leverage `apply(pd.Series)` to expand the resulting dictionaries in each row:

```
exploded = df.explode('values').reset_index(drop=True)
exploded[['value','key']] = exploded['values'].apply(pd.Series)
exploded.drop('values', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Yields:

```
   updated_at    user_id  value key
0  2020-08-18  178414113   3742   0
1  2020-08-18  178414113   3813   1
2  2020-08-18  178414113   3918   2
3  2020-08-18  178414113   2956   3
4  2020-08-19  152285823   3542   0
5  2020-08-19  152285823   2563   1
6  2020-08-19  152285823   3218   2
7  2020-08-19  152285823   2152   3
```

Comment: its giving an error for second line. error:=Columns must be same length as key

Comment: Do the dictionaries contained in the lists have a variable number of key-value pairs? My solution works for the sample data in your original question.

Comment: and the problem is in explode function. it is not splitting  multiple (value and key) dictionary within the list